# Graylog fails when connecting to DocDB

Tags: docker, tls1.2, graylog

I am attempting to bring up Graylog using DocDB as a replacement for MongoDB.  This seems possible, however, we are failing to connect I think due to the TLS cert.  This is the Mongo URI:

```
export GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI='mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@graylogstaging-db-cluster.cluster.us-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/graylog?ssl=true&tlsCAFile=/usr/share/graylog/global-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
```

To run the container, the following is used:

```
docker run -e GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=${GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET} -e GRAYLOG_ELASICSEARCH_HOSTS=${GRAYLOG_ELASICSEARCH_HOSTS} -e GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI=${GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI} -v $(pwd)/global-bundle.pem:/usr/share/graylog/global-bundle.pem -p 9000:9000 2f485f203680
```

I am getting these errors:

```
INFO : org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server graylogstaging-db-cluster.cluster.us-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:687) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:558) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:384) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:332) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:104) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:48) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:134) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:76) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:185) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198) [graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) [graylog.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:102) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:555) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    ... 10 more
```

Starting the Docker container triggers the problems:

```
docker run -e GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=${GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET} -e GRAYLOG_ELASICSEARCH_HOSTS=${GRAYLOG_ELASICSEARCH_HOSTS} -e GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI=${GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI} -v $(pwd)/global-bundle.pem:/usr/share/graylog/global-bundle.pem -p 9000:9000 2f485f203680
```

Comment: Check this error: `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`